# where to place asset files in Cordova 8?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, filepath, readfile

I recently upgraded most of my app, except I am still running on Ionic v1.

```
Cordova CLI: 8.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Version: 1.3.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v6.10.3
```

I used to place some read only files in /platforms/android/assets, and would read them via the standard cordova file structure for Android.  But since I upgraded to Cordova 8.0 the directory structure has changed.

Now my files in the /platforms/android/assets folder are no longer found - where should I move these files too?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
This is my project files for ionic v1 app
[image: this is my project files for a project in ionic v1] inside lib I have my assets for example moment.js

And here is my index.html what I do is lib/moment.js
[image]

Note: in js I have my controllers and services.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and that didn't work, files still not found.

Comment: your files are in root www though, just in sub folder lib...and then you reference a the specific file path.  Using cordova-plugin-file, I am referencing the specifcally defined `dataDirectory` that used to point to `/platforms/android/assets` but now apparently points to somewhere else - the filepaths are specified here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file